# C++ How to implement timeout in serial canonical communications

Tags: c++, serial-port, timeout, termios

I´m using ubuntu as host, and C++ as language.

I´m communicating to a serial device that uses line by line commands. For that purpose I opted for a canonical mode of operation and my `termios` flags are:

```
fd = open(portName.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

struct termios config = { 0 };
config.c_iflag = IGNPAR | ICRNL;
config.c_oflag = 0;
config.c_lflag = ICANON;
config.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | IEXTEN | ISIG);
config.c_cc[VINTR]    = 0;   
config.c_cc[VQUIT]    = 0;   
config.c_cc[VERASE]   = 0;   
config.c_cc[VKILL]    = 0;   
config.c_cc[VEOF]     = 4;   
config.c_cc[VTIME]    = 0;   
config.c_cc[VMIN]     = 0;   
config.c_cc[VSWTC]    = 0;   
config.c_cc[VSTART]   = 0;   
config.c_cc[VSTOP]    = 0;   
config.c_cc[VSUSP]    = 0;   
config.c_cc[VEOL]     = 0;   
config.c_cc[VREPRINT] = 0;   
config.c_cc[VDISCARD] = 0;   
config.c_cc[VWERASE]  = 0;   
config.c_cc[VLNEXT]   = 0;   
config.c_cc[VEOL2]    = 0;   
if(tcsetattr(fd, TCSAFLUSH, &config) < 0)
{
   std::cout << "Error configuring serial." << std::endl;
}
```

And a simple read is done as:

```
char buffer[1024]; // 1024 bytes
read(fd, &buffer[0], 1024);
```

My  problem is that if I loose communication (ie: when the connected device powers off), my read statement hangs and the program gets blocked.

I need to imlpement a timeout where it would return with an error after some seconds. As far as I know, VTIME and VMIN has no effect on canonical reads.

Help appreciated on how to enable timeout for such a read command.

Comment: You could call **select()** with a timeout to check for available data before actually issuing the **read()**.  Or put the read in a thread, and treat the input as an event.  BTW you're not initializing the `struct termios` properly; use **tcgetattr()**.  See [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html)